# Airflow Pentaho Plugin - Status of the DAG is ALWAYS Success

Tags: airflow, pentaho

I've just started using Airflow-Pentaho-Plugin. I have created a transformation on the Pentaho data integration server and have created a connection from Airflow to PDI. I'm using PanOperator & KitchenOperator to trigger Pentaho transformation & jobs respectively. There is a dependency created in the DAG like this: Transformation >> JOB. Even when the transformation fails the status of the Transformation is always green on the job graph and JOB is also getting triggered.  I can see on the log that the transformation has failed. I was expecting that failure should get reported and not run the subsequent downstream. Any suggestions on what am I missing or doing incorrect? My DAG is given below:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow_pentaho.operators.KitchenOperator import KitchenOperator
from airflow_pentaho.operators.PanOperator import PanOperator
from airflow_pentaho.operators.CarteJobOperator import CarteJobOperator
from airflow_pentaho.operators.CarteTransOperator import CarteTransOperator
DAG_NAME = "pdi_example_2"
DEFAULT_ARGS = {
'owner': 'airflow',
'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date': days_ago(2),
'email': ['abc@abc.com'],
'retries': 3,
'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=10),
'email_on_failure': False,
'email_on_retry': False
}
with DAG(dag_id=DAG_NAME,
default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
dagrun_timeout=timedelta(hours=2),
schedule_interval='30 0 * * *') as dag:
trans = PanOperator(
        queue="pdi_2",
        task_id="pdi_example_2",
        directory={},
        file="/path/sample.ktr",
        trans={},
        params={},
        dag=dag)
        
job = KitchenOperator( 
            queue="pdi_3",
            task_id="average_spent",
            directory={},
            job={},
            file="/path/sample.kjb",
            params={},  # Date in yyyy-mm-dd format
            dag=dag)
trans >> job
```

Comment: There is no offical Pentacho provider thus you need to be specific into what is the problem and share the Pentacho integration code.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution to this. Please refer this [link](https://github.com/damavis/airflow-pentaho-plugin/issues/6) for the detailed solution.